# Copy key file to folder using Jenkingfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins scripted file. 
I have .key file stored in jenkins files ( Where all env files are present ). 
And I need to copy that file to code folder. 

Like i want to store `device.key` in `src/auth/keys`.  
Then will run test on code in pipeline.

I am using scripted Jenkinsfile. And i am unable to find any way to this.

```
node{
  def GIT_COMMIT_HASH
  stage('Checkout Source Code and Logging Into Registry') {
          echo 'Logging Into the Private ECR Registry'
          checkout scm
          sh "git rev-parse --short HEAD > .git/commit-id"
          GIT_COMMIT_HASH = readFile('.git/commit-id').trim()
          # NEED TO COPY device.key to /src/auth/key
        }
  stage('TEST'){
    nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName:'node'){
      sh 'npm install'
      sh 'npm test'    
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved this:

- I installed   **Config File Provider Plugin**
- I added the files as custom files for each environment
- In the JenkinsFile I replace the configuration file from the project with the one comming from jenkins:

  `stage('Add Config files') {
  steps {
     configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'ID-of-Jenkins-stored-file', targetLocation: 'relative-path-to-destination-file-in-the-project')]) {
     // some block , maybe a friendly echo for debugging
  } } }`

  Please see the [plugin doc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/config-file-provider-plugin) as it is capable of replacing tokens in XML and json files and many others.